# Why does SCCM report Windows IE v11 as v18?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, sccm

Internet Explorer v11 is on all the machines. However, SCCM reports it as v18. I've performed various Google searches and can't seem to find anything on it. Has anyone ever seen this before? I would also like to know what is causing it and how to resolve it. I'm using SCCM version 18.2

[image: SCCM Internet Explorer Version Report]

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, the 16299.492 part is presumably [this Windows 10 build](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4284819/windows-10-update-kb4284819), namely the 1709 build from 12 June 2018.

Comment: @IMSoP thank you. That is helpful. However, why is it reporting 18 rather than 11 (which is the actual version)?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Incidentally, this should probably be on https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com rather than here, since it's about software / systems, rather than programming.

Comment: you could check [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/14bb9caa-5f0b-418e-88b5-e359ef6d116b/report-to-show-major-internet-explorer-version?forum=configmgrgeneral) and [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/20013ccf-b997-4218-8a85-df5b0d5af094/sccm-reporting-ie-versions?forum=configmgrgeneral) to get the IE version, since this issue is related to SCCM, it is better to post your problem on [SCCM forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/home?category=configurationmanager).

Comment: which report is this? "Computers with a specific product" ?

Comment: @Syberdoor yes it is

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this so I can't say a lot about it but the report is based on v_GS_SoftwareProduct afaik which so it is software inventory based. This means 1) it is based on the files themselves not some registry key and 2) depending on your use case it might be possible to switch to a hardware inventory (i.e. registry value) based report that might not be affected by the same bug.